# Create New Service account programmatically

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-account, android-for-work

Is there an Google Admin API to create a new service account using the credentials of another service account?

I'm creating a SAAS solution where I'm providing certain services to end users from different domains. Google recommends (not restricts) to use different service account (ESA) for each domain so that their data is entirely segregated.

To achieve this, I need to create a new ESA programmatically whenever a new customer signsup.

I'm able to provide the services to all users (from different domains) using single ESA, but I was not able to find any API that allows me to create a new ESA programmatically. Is it possible?

Comment: If you're not sharing the service account credentials with end users, there should be no security risk in using a single service account for many domains.

Comment: Android suggests the use of multiple ESA not because the keys can be compromised, but to keep each customer's data segregated.

Comment: Please update your question with details about the app and platform you are trying to use and links to the docs you are referring to.

Comment: I'm creating an EMM solution using Google play API and [this](https://developers.google.com/android/work/overview#service_accounts) document says _we recommend that you use any given ESA for only one customer, which ensures data separation among your customers_